# R: Multiplying elements of data frame with neighbours

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 300x300 elements. Each of them are either -1 or +1:

```
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,]   1     -1     -1   
[2,]   1      1      1  
[3,]  -1     -1      1  
[4,]   1      1     -1
```

What I want is to iterate over my data frame, and multiply each value with every neighbouring value.
I.e:
For element [1,1] in my original data frame I want the product of [1,1], [1,2] and [2,1]
For element [2,2] in my original data frame I want the product of [2,2], [1,2], [2,1], [2,3] and [3,2].

I have tried to create 4 new data frames, each shifted 1 element to the right, left, up and down, respectively:

```
x_up <- shift(x, 1, dir='up')
x_up <- as.array(x_up)
dim(x_up) <- dims
x_down <- shift(x, 1, dir='down')
x_down <- as.array(x_down)
dim(x_down) <- dims
x_left <- shift(x, 1, dir='left')
x_left <- as.array(x_left)
dim(x_left) <- dims
x_right <- shift(x, 1, dir='right')
x_right <- as.array(x_right)
dim(x_right) <- dims
```

where x is my original data frame.
I can see when I used this approach, the new data frames are not rightfully shiftet; more of them are identical. I checked this with identical().

Is there another approach to my problem?

Edit:
shift() is of the 'binhf' library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's probably a smarter way to do this, but the standard approach would be iterating over each element and multiplying its surroundings.

Starting with:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1), ncol=3)
```

In order to avoid problems on positive margins, you must add a column and a row of `1`'s as margins (positive 1 won't be a problem when multiplying, if you were summing it would have to be `0`'s, for example).

```
mat2 <- addmargins(mat, FUN=function(x) 1)
```

Now you create an empty matrix to hold the output, and then iterate over the elements and multiply the neighbors.

```
out <- matrix(nrow=nrow(mat), ncol=ncol(mat))
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    out[i,j] <- prod(mat[i,j], mat2[i-1, j], mat2[i, j-1], mat2[i+1, j], mat2[i, j+1])
  }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    1    1
[2,]   -1    1   -1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]   -1    1   -1
```

This took less than a second for a 300x300 matrix, so it might be enough for you.

Comment: @user20650 I forgot to multiply by the element itself, fixed that, thanks.

Comment: I get an error: Error in x2[i - 1, j] : incorrect number of dimensions. My data is in a large array - would this solution apply to that or should I convert it?

Comment: What do you mean by large array? If it has 2 dimensions, it's a matrix. If it doesn't, the code will fail because it's trying to access dimensions `i` and `j` (row/col).

Comment: It might be a problem caused when I created my data frame. I have imported a binary png-file, and I can see it imports it as an array of dimensions 300 300 3. I Am trying to convert it to a matrix of 300x300 and rerun the code. 
Sorry for not having done this prior to asking.

Comment: @MadsObi Oh, that indeed happens when you read an image as binary. Is this some kind of image smoothing?

Comment: Molx: Yes. I am trying to implement an energy function and later use ICM approach to smoothing the picture. Next step now is implementing the ICM. With vague programming skills it becomes harder :) Also I figured I actually wanted the sum of all product of xi and it's neighbours xj, but I edited that myself :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78037/discussion-between-mads-obi-and-molx).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
ind <- which(x==x, arr.ind=TRUE) # index matrix

# find distances (need distances of 1 or 0) 
dist.mat <- as.matrix(dist(ind))
inds2mult <- apply(dist.mat, 1, function(ii) which(ii <= 1))

# get product of each list element in inds2mult
# and reform into appropriate matrix
matrix(
    sapply(inds2mult, function(ii) prod(unlist(x)[ii])),
    ncol=ncol(x))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   -1    1    1
#[2,]   -1    1   -1
#[3,]    1    1    1
#[4,]   -1    1   -1
```

To get around memory issues with large matrices in the call to `dist`, you can try the `fields.rdist.near` function (with a delta value of 1) from the `fields` package:

```
x <- matrix(rep(-1, 300*300), ncol=300)

ind <- which(x==x, arr.ind=TRUE) # index matrix

library(fields)
ind.list <- fields.rdist.near(ind, delta=1) # took my computer ~ 15 - 20 seconds

inds2mult <- tapply(ind.list$ind[,2], ind.list$ind[,1], list)

matrix(
    sapply(inds2mult, function(ii) prod(unlist(x)[ii])),
    ncol=ncol(x))
```

The delta argument from the `fields.rdist.near` help page:

> Threshhold distance. All pairs of points that separated by more
>   than delta in distance are ignored.

Comment: i like this but `dist` gets pretty expensive as the matrix size increases... runs out of memory on my old lappie for a 300x300 matrix

Comment: @user20650 Oops, should have tried on a larger matrix before posting.  I'll try to improve on it.

Comment: I get an error: cannot allocate vector of size 271.6 Gb, so it might not work for my data frame.

Comment: @MadsObi See the `fields.rdist.near` approach to avoid the allocation issue.

Comment: @Frank: I have read it lightly, as Molx answer worked for me. I appreciate your answer though!